# Show/Hide Badge/Label if Post is Older Than a [Set Number of Days]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I found this [code](http://gph.is/1KjihQe)

```
function is_old_post($days = 5) {
    $days = (int) $days;
    $offset = $days*60*60*24;
    if ( get_post_time() < date('U') - $offset )
         return true; 
    return false;
 }

if ( is_old_post(10) ) {
  // do something if the post is old
  } else {
  // do something if the post is not old
}
```

I would like to make `.my-sweet-label` appear if the post is new and make it disappear if the post is more than **30 days old**.

my post is in CPT named property.

if I understood correctly this code is missing some jquery to tell my-sweet-label to do the [magical appears / disappears](http://gph.is/1KjihQe)

for my example I simply use a button placed in a card with elementor nothing extraodinary, as you can see in the picture.

[image]

**UPDATE 20/12/2020**

I did not expect it to work this way but I managed to get it to work with a shortcode system I put it where I have my posts

I just noticed a slight problem if I put loading more button to [posts] they show up like this.
strange ...
I do not know where this may be a conflict with ajax?

```
/* Show / Hide badge if post is new (7 days) */
function newly_posted() {
global $post;
$now = date('U'); $published = get_the_time('U');
$new = false;
if( $now-$published  <= 7*24*60*60 ) $new = true;
return $new;
}

/* Shortcode for wordpress posts */
add_shortcode( 'new-post', function () {

if( newly_posted() ) 
    
    $out = '<p id="new-post">New</p>';
    return $out;
} );
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Comment: jqueryhtmlcss I Updated my post :)

Comment: It's not about modernity. The issue with the other answer is that even though its idea is sound, it mixes up things and tries to call a PHP function via Javascript. Probably the other answerer did not realize that is_old_post is a PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your CSS I can't give an exact example for your case, but you can make use of the JQuery `hide()` and `show()` (presuming you're using JQuery).

```
if ( is_old_post(10) ) {
  // hide button
   $(".yourButtonClassHere").hide();
  } else {
  // show button
  $(".yourButtonClassHere").show();
}
```

Amend the `yourButtonClassHere` to match the class of your button - note ensure it's a unique class so the JS doesn't end up hiding other elements on page too.

Comment: This will not work, is_old_post is a PHP function, you cannot call it like this in Javascript. PHP functions are to be evaluated on server-side, before the content is sent out to the browser and Javascript will only be evaluated in the browser, once it arrives there.

Comment: Oh yeah whoops 

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code generates stuff that will be part of the HTML. So, let's add a `script`.

```
function is_old_post($days = 5) {
    $days = (int) $days;
    $offset = $days*60*60*24;
    if ( get_post_time() < date('U') - $offset )
         return true; 
    return false;
 }

?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".my-sweet-label").<?php echo is_old_post(10) ? "hide" : "show"; ?>();
    });
</script>
```

So, we have a script which runs on page load, to make sure that you have your button at that point. We find the button by the selector and evaluate (on server-side, before the `script` is sent out to the browser) whether it is old. If so, then our Javascript will call the `hide` `function`. Otherwise it will call the `show` `function`.

Comment: thank you Lajos Arpad
I created 10 posts in CPT property and normal posts I put 5 posts date= today and 5 date= 30 days before, I put my button label I put the snippet, but the button it didn't work does not disappear . I think something is missing